# how to configure laravel 5 in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: laravel-5

i installed laravel5 in Ubuntu 12.04 and I have updated version of xampp with php 5.5.1. Actually i don't want to make any mistake thats why i asked this questions because most of the time i had face pdo exception plus sql server errors only because of wrong config settings.

Below is my app.php file

return [

```
/*
 Application Debug Mode

*/

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

/*
 Application URL

*/

'url' => 'http://localhost',

/*
 Application Timezone

*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
   Application Locale Configuration

*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
 Application Fallback Locale

*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

/*
 Encryption Key

*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

/*

*/

'log' => 'single',

/*
```

Autoloaded Service Providers

```
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],


'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

],
```

];

Below is my database.php file.

return [

```
/*

*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*

*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
 Database Connections

*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],


'migrations' => 'migrations',



'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

];

Comment: What is your question exactly? We can't help you properly unless you are running in to trouble with a particular problem.

Comment: the basic problem is i can't install migrate using command php artisan migrate:install. when i run this i have got error i.e [PDOException]                                                           
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server    and through sock  and one more thing i don't get any .env file in my project folder. this file will exists in folder when we install laravel5 on windows.  
  et '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: these are following changes i had made in my database.php file 'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lovey'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

Comment: If there is no .env file, then you should definitely create one. Is there a .env.example file?